# Adding Decimal Places (3 Decimal Places) in Java

Tags: java, rounding

I was wondering how to make `avg` in the following program round to 3 decimal places:

```
public class BaseballCalculator {
    public static void main(String args[])  {
        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        double atBats;
        double baseHits;
        double onBase;
        double avg;
        double onBasePercentage;

        System.out.println("How many atbats did you have? ");
            atBats = myScanner.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("How many base hits and homeruns did you have? ");
            baseHits = myScanner.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("How many times did you get a hit by pitch or walk? ");
            onBase = myScanner.nextDouble();

        avg = baseHits / atBats;
        onBasePercentage = (baseHits + onBase) / atBats;

        System.out.println("You have a total of " + baseHits + " base hits for the season");
        System.out.println("You have a total of " + atBats + " at bats for the season");
        System.out.println("Your average for the game or season is: " + avg);
        System.out.println("Your on base percentage for the game or year is: " + onBasePercentage);
    }
}
```

Comment: look at [`String.format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)) and follow the link that explains what a format string looks like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`String.format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) to format your output to 3 decimal places.  The output is rounded.

```
System.out.println("Your average for the game or season is: " +
    String.format("%.3f", avg));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to user `DecimalFormat` class to format your number using a pattern.

You can do this:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.000");
String average = df.format(avg); // double 3.0 will be formatted as string "3.000"
```

Another way to format a number is using the `String.format`, like this:

```
String average = String.format("%.1f", avg); // average = "5.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

The number of zeroes is the number of decimal places you want to round to:

```
double avg = ((int) (1000 * Math.round(avg))) / 1000;
```

Comment: Absolutely do not do this! For a few reasons: you may exceed max int, you may incur rounding errors internally in the double, converting an int to a double and diving by 1000 will almost always not give only 3 digits after the decimal point. 
Using `printf` or `String.format` is the correct way to do this.

Comment: (1) Exceeding max int: good point.  Could also cast as long instead of int though.  (2) Rounding errors: also good point.  (3) "will almost always not give only 3 digits": Depends on the double and this one was pre-vetted.

Comment: @ggovan If you know someone whose batting average could cause this expression to exceed the maximum integer, please give their name to Mike Scioscia...  (P.S. your comment is correct, but not everything needs to be worried about in every situation...)

Answer (score 0):

If the number has to be rounded just for output, you can do it by using `printf`:

```
System.out.printf("Your average for the game or season is: %.3f%n", avg);
```